# CLOSED How to set overScrollMode=never without disable fadingEdge?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-listview

I have a RecyclerView. I need to set the value of overScrollMode = "never" to remove [this animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8J0TR.png) , but at the same time the fadingEdge option is disabled. Can you help me turn off the animation about which I wrote above, without disabling fadingEdge?

**SOLUTION**

If you do this in XML, then when you disable OverScrollMode - fading also becomes inaccessible, but if you do it programmatically, everything will work.

```
recyclerView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
recyclerView.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
recyclerView.setFadingEdgeLength(Math.round(30 * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density));
```

**SOLUTION 2**

@RakeshKumar proposed an option with XML. In order for fading not to disappear, you must also specify the background for RecyclerView.

```
android:background="YOUR COLOR"
android:fadingEdgeLength="30dp"
android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
android:overScrollMode="never"
```

Comment: `android:overScrollMode="never"` with a white background will work for you.

Comment: @RakeshKumar, yes, you're right!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this like following:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:overScrollMode="never"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:fadingEdgeLength="30dp"
                    android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"/>
```

Comment: @Vlad Adrian, If above post worked for you then make this answer as correct and upvote so that it will help to other users as well.

Comment: SOLUTION 2 in the question :)

Comment: Happy coding buddy. :)

Comment: If anyone is curious HOW this actually fixes the problem and was too lazy to read the second solution in the question: adding a background to the RecyclerView (or ListView) will allow fadingEdge to work with overScrollMode set to never.